# win32: simulate a click without simulating mouse movement?

Tags: python, winapi, input, automation, mouse

I'm trying to simulate a mouse click on a window. I currently have success doing this as follows (I'm using Python, but it should apply to general win32):

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
```

This works fine. However, if the click happens while I'm moving the mouse manually, the cursor position gets thrown off. Is there any way to send a click directly to a given `(x,y)` coordinate without moving the mouse there? I've tried something like the following with not much luck:

```
nx = x*65535/win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0)
ny = y*65535/win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | \
                     win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE,nx,ny)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP | \
                     win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE,nx,ny)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try WindowFromPoint() function:

```
POINT pt;
    pt.x = 30; // This is your click coordinates
    pt.y = 30;

HWND hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);
LPARAM lParam = MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, MK_RBUTTON, lParam);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_RBUTTONUP, MK_RBUTTON, lParam);
```

Comment: The coordinates I have are absolute coordinates, though, not coordinates relative to the window position.. will PostMessage transmit them as absolute ones or as ones relative to the window? I actually could get the hwnd already, but just translating my coords to `(x - left, y - top)`, where I got `left` and `top` from `GetWindowRect` didn't click in the right spot.

Comment: Ah, really. You need to convert an absolute click position into the relative. Use ScreenToClient(hWnd, lpPoint) before PostMessage

Comment: ah ty, i'll try that! is there any diff between postmessage and sendmessage in this case?

Comment: I think there is no difference between postmessage and sendmessage in this case.

Comment: Hey, where is `MAKELPARAM` come from?

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't answer the question, but it does solve my problem:

```
win32api.ClipCursor((x-1,y-1,x+1,y+1))
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN| \
                     win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP| \
                     win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE,0,0)
win32api.ClipCursor((0,0,0,0))
```

The result is that any movements I'm making won't interfere with the click. The downside is that my actual movement will be messed up, so I'm still open to suggestions.